# Adding up the values of 2 objects

Tags: javascript

The price of a fruit is defined in object `prices`, while the fruit's quantity in stock is in `stocks`.

**Question:** How do you find the total value of all the fruits? Usig `for.. in`, I can access the values in `stocks`, but I am having trouble accessing the values of `prices`.

```
prices = {'appleusd': 1, 'orangeusd': 10};
stocks = {'apple': 100, 'orange': 20};

totalValue = 0;

for (stock in stocks){
    totalValue += stocks[stock] + prices[stock+'usd'];
}

console.log(totalValue);
```

Comment: You're having trouble because your objects have different keys.  There's nothing to relate the two, really, unless you say `prices[stock + 'usd']`.  Though personally, i'd say `stock = { apple: { stock: 100, price_usd: 1 }, orange: { stock: 20, price_usd: 10 } };` and have one set of stuff to loop over.

Comment: You'll also want to multiply the two values.

Answer (score 3):

Because the keys found in `prices` and `stocks` are different, you'll have to append `usd` to the stock key to get the correct price. Then you will need to multiply the price by the stock quantity, and add the results to `totalValue` with each iteration:

```
prices = {'appleusd': 1, 'orangeusd': 10};
stocks = {'apple': 100, 'orange': 20};

totalValue = 0;

for (var stock in stocks){
    totalValue += stocks[stock] * prices[stock + 'usd'];
}

console.log(totalValue); // 300
```

Edit: It seems that since I first posted this, you've already edited the code to address some of the points I've raised here. The only remaining error is that your code adds the two values together instead of multiplying them.

Answer (score 0):

A fast example:

```
prices = {'appleusd': 1, 'orangeusd': 10};

sum = 0;
for (var fruit in prices) {
    alert("The fruit " + fruit + " has price " + prices[fruit]);
    sum += prices[fruit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same key for `prices` and `stocks`.

```
prices = {'apple': 1, 'orange': 10};
stocks = {'apple': 100, 'orange': 20};

totalValue = 0;

for (fruit in stocks){
    totalValue += stocks[fruit] * prices[fruit];
}

console.log(totalValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to group your collection so that it makes more sense:

```
var stock = {
  apple: {
    quantity: 100,
    priceusd: 1
  },
  orange: {
    quantity: 20,
    priceusd: 10
  }
}

function getTotalValue() {
  var totalValue = 0;
  for (var item in stock) {
    totalValue += stock[item].quantity * stock[item].priceusd;
  }
  return totalValue;
}

var totalValue = getTotalValue();
console.log(totalValue); // 300
```